# sql Как поделить в таблице записи на 2 группы и отсортировать их по полю

Tags: sql

Пишу поднятие объявлений в списке на сайте (будет использоваться пагинация). Нужно, чтобы платные объявления были вверху списка, а бесплатные внизу, при этом нужно обновлять объявления. Ну и естественно нужно сделать так, чтобы бесплатные обновлялись среди бесплатных, а платные среди платных. Это нужно реализовать как-то одним запросом, чтобы можно было использовать пагинацию, передовая позицию последней выведенной записи и количество записей на странице. Как это сделать? Пытался через UNION соединить 2 запроса, но сортировать можно только один раз в конце всего запроса.

Comment: Сортировку можно делать не только по полям, но и по происзольным условиям, например `order by case when тип=платное then 1 else 2 end, дата` сделает платные первыми и уже внутри этих групп отсортирует по дате

Comment: Спасибо, помогло